# Ecore TreeIterator missing root object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

i have the following problem: I want to iterate through my Ecore model, using a TreeIterator.

However, the root element is always skipped, is there a way to get the RootElement in the TreeIterator loop ?

```
EPackage rootElement = (EPackage) EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(model);
for (TreeIterator iter = EcoreUtil.getAllProperContents(rootElement, true); iter.hasNext();) {
EObject element = iter.next()... // I want the root element to be the first element here!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Resource res = model.eResource();
TreeIterator<EObject> allContents = res.getAllContents();
```

Comment: Resource res = model.eResource() returns null

Comment: You model should be contained by a resource for this to work.